# Operação matemática com arquivos CSV

Tags: csv, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Olá!

importei um arquivo .csv com algumas colunas e gostaria de fazer cálculos com estes dados, porém não sei como fazer isto.

Exemplo como seria no excel:
[image: exemplo no excel]

Answer (score 1):

É complicado sugerir uma solução quando é disponibilizado apenas uma imagem de um excel e não uma amostra real dos dados. Mas se o que você procura é a multiplicação entre colunas e salvar isso em outra, você pode fazer assim:

```
df['resultado'] = df['nome de uma das colunas'] * df['nome de outra coluna']
```